# Edit Delete and save in stream reader c# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I need your help please.I am using C#  Visual Studio 2010 and I need to be able to read from a file and display the Data in to the relevant text boxes.
The text file is a list of Football Teams and I have to Display, Edit, Delete and save the file. I have done some research and used YouTube to create programs that use Stream Readers but they don't do what I want them to do. I understand how stream readers reads the data but I am having difficulties in Displaying the data LINE BY LINE in the relevant boxes IE: Team Name, Team Manager, Team Stadium etc. I have made the class for Team which is listed below along with the Forms Code that i am having problems with. Any Help would be much appreciated.

My Class: Team
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

```
namespace The_F.A__Soft130_Assignment_
{
    class Team
    {

        private string Name;
        private string League;
        private string Manager;
        private string Nickname;
        private string Stadium;        
        private int Position;
        private int Points;
        private int GamesPlayed;
        private int GoalDiff;
        private string Logo;
        private int NumberPlayers;


        // constructor

        public Team(string theName, string theLeague, string theManager,
                    string theNickname, string theStadium, string thePosition,
                    string thePoints, string theGamesPlayed,string theGoalDiff,
                    string theLogo, string theNumberPlayers)
        {
            Name = theName;
            League = theLeague;
            Manager = theManager;
            Nickname = theNickname;
            Stadium = theStadium;
            setPosition(thePosition);
            setPoints(thePoints);
            setGamesPlayed(theGamesPlayed);
            setGoalDiff(theGoalDiff);
            Logo = theLogo;
            setNumberPlayers(theNumberPlayers);
        }


        public Team(string theName, string theLeague, string theManager,
                    string theNickname, string theStadium,
                    string theLogo, string theNumberPlayers)
    {
        Name = theName;
        League = theLeague;
        Manager = theManager;
        Nickname = theNickname;
        Stadium = theStadium;
        Logo = theLogo;
        setNumberPlayers(theNumberPlayers);
    }

        //The getter methods
        public string getName()
        {
            return Name;
        }
        public string getLeague()
        {
            return League;
        }
        public string getManager()
        {
            return Manager;
        }
        public string getNickname()
        {
            return Nickname;
        }
        public string getStadium()
        {
            return Stadium;
        }


        public int getPosition()
        {
            return Position;
        }
        public int getPoints()
        {
            return Points;
        }
        public int getGamesPlayed()
        {
            return GamesPlayed;
        }
        public int getGoalDiff()
        {
            return GoalDiff;
        }
        public string getLogo()
        {
            return Logo;
        }
        public int getNumberPlayers()
        {
            return NumberPlayers;
        } 

        // all the Class setter methods
        public void setName(string theName)
        {
            Name = theName;
        }
        public void setLeague(string theLeague)
        {
            League = theLeague;
        }
        public void setManager(string theManager)
        {
            Manager = theManager;
        }
        public void setNickname(string theNickname)
        {
            Nickname = theNickname;
        }
        public void setStadium(string theStadium)
        {
            Stadium = theStadium;
        }


        public void setPosition(string thePosition)
            {
                try
            {
                Position = Convert.ToInt32(thePosition);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message
                    + "Please input a valid of number");
            }
        }

        public void setPoints(string thePoints)
        {
            try
            {
                Points = Convert.ToInt32(thePoints);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message
                    + "Please input a valid number");

            }
        }

        public void setGamesPlayed(string theGamesPlayed)
        {
            try
            {
                GamesPlayed = Convert.ToInt32(theGamesPlayed);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message
                    + "Please in put valid number");

            }
        }

        public void setGoalDiff(string theGoalDiff)
        {
            try
            {
                GoalDiff = Convert.ToInt32(theGoalDiff);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message
                    + "Please input valid number");
            }
        }

        public void setLogo(string theLogo)
        {
             Logo = theLogo;
        }

        public void setNumberPlayers(string theNumberPlayers)
        {
            try
            {
                NumberPlayers = Convert.ToInt32(theNumberPlayers);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error:" + e.Message
                    + "Please input Valid Number");
            }
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace The_F.A__Soft130_Assignment_
{
    public partial class frmEditTeam : Form
     {
        public frmEditTeam()
        {
            InitializationComponent();
        }

        private void InitializationComponent()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        //EDIT Team --- EDIT Team --- EDIT Team --- EDIT Team --- EDIT Team --- EDIT   
        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool allInputOK = false;
            League whichLeague = (League)frmFA.Leagues[frmFA.leagueSelected];



            //get inputs - Team ORDER = Author Title Year Copies Isbn
            string tempName = txtEditTeamName.Text;
            string tempLeague = txtEditTeamLeague.Text;
            string tempManager = txtEditTeamManager.Text;
            string tempNickname = txtEditTeamNickname.Text;
            string tempStadium = txtEditTeamStadium.Text;
            string templogo = txtEditTeamlogo.Text;

            int tempNoOfPlayers = txtEditTeamNoofPlayers.Text;
            int tempPosition;
            int tempPoints;
            int tempGamePlayed;
            int tempGoalDiff;
            //final validation check
            allInputOK = Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamName, "Team name") &&     Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamLeague, "Team league")
                    && Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamManager, "Team manager") && Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamNickname, "Team Nickname")
                    && Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamStadium, "Team stadium") && Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamlogo, "Team logo")
                    && Utilities.notNullTextBox(txtEditTeamNoofPlayers, "Team number of players") 
                    && Utilities.validNumber(txtTeamPosition, "The Teams Position")
                    && Utilities.validNumber(txtTeamPoints, " The Teams Points") && Utilities.validNumber(txtTeamGamesPlayed, "Games Played")
                    && Utilities.validNumber(txtTeamGoalDiff, " The Goal Differance");

        //create Team if all ok
        if (allInputOK)
        {
            Team temp = new Team(tempName, tempLeague, tempManager, tempNickname, tempStadium, tempPosition, tempPoints, tempGamePlayed, tempGoalDiff, templogo, tempNoOfPlayers);
            whichLeague.replaceTeam(whichLeague.getleagueAllTeams(), temp,frmFA.teamselected);





           Utilities.WriteAllLeagueTeams(frmFA.inputDataFile1, frmFA.Leagues);// update file
            MessageBox.Show("Success: Team " + tempName + " edited in " + whichLeague.getleagueName());//finish up
            resetForm();
        }
    }

    //LOAD Team DETAILS --- LOAD Team DETAILS --- LOAD Team DETAILS --- LOAD Team DETAILS --- 
    private void getTeamDetails()
    {
        //convert this to the corrcet team reference
        //int selected team = frmFA.Team Selected;
        int selectedTeam = frmFA.teamSelected;
        int selectedLeague = frmFA.leagueSelected;

        //GET Team               
        //starting out with access to all the leagues
        ArrayList allLeagues = frmFA.Leagues;
        //narrow it down to which League you want
        League currentLeague = (League)allLeagues[selectedLeague];
        //narrow it down to which Team you want form that League
        Team currentTeam = (Team)currentLeague.getleagueAllTeams()[selectedTeam];

        //get Team details
        txtEditTeamName.Text = currentTeam.getName();
        txtEditTeamManager = currentTeam.getManager();
        txtEditTeamStadium.Text = currentTeam.getStadium();
        txtEditTeamNoofPlayers.Text = currentTeam.getNoOfPlayers();
        txtEditTeamLeague.Text = currentTeam.getTeamLeague();
        txtEditTeamLogo.Text = currentTeam.getTeamlogo();


    }
    // event procedure
    private void btnHomeAdd_Team_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmFA form = new frmFA(); form.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    private void btnRefreshClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }
    private void btnEditTeamUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmEditTeam form = new frmEditTeam();
        form.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }


    private void txtEditTeamName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getTeamName();
    }

    private void txtEditTeamLeague_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getTeamLeague();
    }

    private void txtEditTeamManager_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getTeamManager();
    }

    private void txtEditTeamNickName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getTeamNickName();
    }

    private void txtEditTeamStadium_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getTeamStadium();
    }
    private void txtEditTeamLogo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getLogo();
    }
    private void txtEditTeamNoofPlayers_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getNoOfPlayers();
    }

    private void txtEditTeamNickname_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getTeamNickname();
    }
    private void resetForm()
    {
        txtName.Text = "";
        txtLeague.Text = "";
        txtManager.Text = "";
        txtNickname.Text = "";
        txtStadium.Text = "";
        txtPosition.Text = "";
        txtPoints.Points = "";
        txtGamesPlayed.GamesPlayed = "";
        txtGoalDiff.GoalDiff = "";
        txtLogo.Logo = "";
        txtNoOfPlayers = "";
        txtName.Focus();
    }

    private void btnEditTeamUpdate_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void frmEditTeam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please share your code that includes the bits that aren't working (streamreader).  That will give us something to go by.

Comment: stream readers aren't for writing.

Comment: also might i suggest properties?

Comment: you can use CTOR overload, to save the first 8 fields update. also, you should use properties, not create a getter/setters as you would do in Java. to actually write data to files, you need stream writer not reader, delet can be done using the File.Delete, but as @Cj S said, share the code that doesn't work.

Comment: What is the format of the file that you are trying to read?  Where is the code for the `streamreader` where you are reading the data?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a basic outline, but what I'd do,

- use a `StreamReader` to load your data in
- use your own classes to manage your data while the application is running
- use a `StreamWriter` when you decide you want to save your data, you should probably save in response to some sort of button.